# How to change the decimal separator string with others commas? C#

Tags: c#, string, char

I have a strings

```
var myString1 = "123,456 + Math.Pow(78,9)";
var myString2 = "123,456 + Math.Pow(78,9,2)";
```

I need to change all decimal separators to '.', but I shouldn't break Math.Pow (and others functions too) parameters. And all functions should work obviously.

Result should be

```
myString1 = "123.456 + Math.Pow(78,9)"
myString2 = "123.456 + Math.Pow(78.9,2)"
```

What is the fastest and easiest way to do this?

Comment: I think you would need to write some custom code

Comment: Why is `78.9,2` not `78,9.2`?

Comment: Why is 78.9,2 not 78,9.2? Good question, let's take the only integer degree by default.

Comment: I think this is an xy-problem and it would be much easier to use the right CultureInfo wherever you  generate or process this string instead of string manipulation.

Comment: What does integer degree mean? integer power? But as you said "others functions", will you define a rule for each function?

Comment: You get string from outside on your API endpoint and can't control format. Inside your code CultureInfo works, yes.

Comment: I mean, in my case I want to take only integer degree in Math.Pow function. For example Math.Pow(double X,int Y).

Answer (score 0):

We can try doing a regex replacement on:

```
(?<!\S)(\d+),(\d+)(?!\S)
```

and then replace with `$1.$2`.  Sample code:

```
var myString2 = "123,456 + Math.Pow(78,9,2)";
var output = Regex.Replace(myString2, @"(?<!\S)(\d+),(\d+)(?!\S)", "$1.$2");
Console.WriteLine(output);  // 123.456 + Math.Pow(78,9,2)
```

The regex pattern used above insists that the `X,Y` comma decimal number be surrounded on both sides by either whitespace or start/end of the string.

Comment: Yes, regex is the simplest way. What about functions, which can take only 2 arguments? Math.Pow(78,9,2) doesn't work.